# How to simulate a Lego EV3 sensor on RaspberryPi UART (Tx,Rx) ports?

Tags: python, pyserial, uart, gpio, lego-mindstorms

I'm trying to simulate the protocol of a digital sensor (in this case the color sensor) but I'm not having success.
Actions:
1) I recovered the digital sign
2) I simulated the digital sign by sending a message on the TX port (from RaspPi to EV3)
Problems:
1) The problem is that I think that the EV3 protocol communication is something like a 485 and the RaspPi use TTL. (I want to simulate that by programming and not physically)
2) Apparently I have well simulated the sign (using pull-downs and a menssage), but I have no answer from EV3
Anyone knows something about this communication?
Or have any material to share?

Comment: raspberrypi+rs485 is what you want to search for ... there are usb adapters you can buy(or shields that use the rpi gpio pins) ... same with arduino (the shields bit at least)   (this assumes rs485 is what you meant by something like 485)

Comment: EV3 uses 3.3V logic levels. It has a generic UART. It is not RS485. What you mean by "digital sign"? Do you mean the EV3 Color sensor or the NXT Color sensor?

Comment: The EV3, my idea is to create a new sensor (an camera/vision sensor) for Lego Mindstorm EV3. I think that the best idea is to simulate the protocole from digital sensors as the color sensor. But I did it, i already simulate that on RaspPi but now i'm trying to do the same with intel Edison but i'm having some problems.